# Android Studio - "aidl is missing"... no, it's not

Tags: android

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example) to try and fix this error...

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>   aidl is missing"

I put "IInAppBillingService.aidl" in "app/src/main/aidl/com.android.vending.billing" and when I rebuild the project, the error is still there. I've restarted Android Studio multiple times... it just won't fix, I've followed the guide to the letter, it's worked for everyone else...

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Well, the AIDL would need to be in `app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/`, from a filesystem directory standpoint. That being said, there's something strange going on with Android Studio -- I created a brand-new project earlier today and got this error, without any code changes, just what the new-project template gave me. I had to remove `appcompat-v7` and fix up my `buildToolsVersion` to get it to build. Could you post your `app/` module's `build.gradle` file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30548289/2911458 may be helpful, or you can roll back the build tools version. See also https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175080&q=aidl&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Here's the build.gradle file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjpap84iup9enew/build.gradle?dl=0 - should I downgrade to build tools 22.0.1?

Comment: Yep, downgrading sorted this.

Answer (score 20):

For anybody getting this error, see the suggestion provided in the comments above by CommonsWare. Downgrade your SDK Build Tools to 22.0.1, it's 23.0.0_rc1 by default.

Comment: accept your own answer.. to help others with this error.

Comment: Agreed with @MounirElfassi

Comment: Just to be clear, right/option click your project, go to Open Module Settings, and change the value via Build Tools Version

Answer (score 2):

Changing the **Build Tools Version** from 23.0.0 rc1 to **22.0.1** in the Project Structure, then **Clean** and **Rebuild** worked for me.
If you changed the build tools and the problem wasn't fixed, try cleaning and rebuilding, and maybe closing Android Studio and reopening it.

Answer (score 1):

To build your application without `aidl is missing` error with `compileSdkVersion 23` and `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` you should specify latest versions for Android and Google Play Services (only if you are using them) Gradle plugins in main `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.1'
    }
}
```